# Batch-VBScript Send specific key(s) specific number of times

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript, automation, active-window

As I asked in the Question title, how can I avoid repetitive typing of key(s) when I have to send that key multiple times.

Below is my Batch-VBScript hybrid where in, for sending `{DOWN}` key 4 times, I tried the below code but it didn't work ?:

```
FINDSTR /E "'VbsCode" %~f0 > %temp%\~temp.vbs
CSCRIPT //NOLOGO %temp%\~temp.vbs
Sub TestAppAuto 'VbsCode
    On Error Resume Next 'VbsCode
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell") 'VbsCode
    WshShell.Visible = False 'VbsCode
    WshShell.Run "test.app",0 'VbsCode
    WScript.Sleep 500 : WshShell.AppActivate "Test Window Title" 'VbsCode
    WScript.Sleep 500 : WshShell.sendKeys "{DOWN}{4}" 'VbsCode
    :: Instead of WScript.Sleep 500 : WshShell.sendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}" 'VbsCode
End Sub 'VbsCode
TestAppAuto 'VbsCode
WScript.Quit 0 'VbsCode
```

How can I achieve what I want ?

Comment: How do repeat anything in VBScript? Use a `For` or `Do` loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanently press key via vbs (Keep key pressed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422088/permanently-press-key-via-vbs-keep-key-pressed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Help http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe

> You can use the `SendKeys` method to send a pattern of keystrokes that
> consists of a single keystroke pressed several times in a row. To do
> this, create a compound string argument that specifies the keystroke
> you want to repeat, followed by the number of times you want it
> repeated. You do this using a compound string argument of the form
> {keystroke number}. For example, to send the letter "`x`" ten times,
> you would send the string argument "`{x 10}`". Be sure to include a
> space between keystroke and number.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a for loop in my VBS script that needed multiple key presses to raise youtube volume.

```
For i = 0 to 20
WshShell.SendKeys ("{RIGHT}")
Next
```

It is both cleaner and easier to edit.